# Findstr command to find a range of IPs in text file 

Tags: findstr

Im my script I issued Arp-a command and piped it to a text file. in need of a findstr command to find a range of IPs in the ARP text file.

Comment: ignoring the insulting comment....but i am stuck ...their a peice of my script which calls c:\Windows\System32\arp.exe -a >>%logfile% 2>&1 Im getting the results that im wanting...but Im trying to clean my log file up a little....so i was wondering is their a was i can do a findstr command that will only find a specific range of IPs in the list of IPs....

Comment: it would be alot easier if i could ping on the network but due to security policies i cant ping. so thats the reason I have to go with the ARP -a command to get the IPs

Comment: for Jure C. So basically what im wanting is when I issue command "call c:\Windows\System32\arp.exe -a" it pipes results to a text file. which works great! what i cant figure out is how to write a findstr command that will look to the arp text file and find a specific range of IP and write results to another log file...

Comment: That's a much better question :) Can you please update you question and the title and tags so you will reach correct experts on SO?

Comment: I got it figured out. In my script after it calls c:\Windows\System32\arp.exe -a" I pipe the result to a text file then added command findstr /r "162.*221" C:\Temp\temp0\arp.log>>%logfile% 2>&1 I repeated the command for every ip in the range i was trying to find. works great! thanks for your response.

Comment: Could you please modify your original question so all the information that you have written in the comments are there. Afterwards answer your own question with the solution and accept it.